# how to add a value on input field when appending it to DOM using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a value to the `input` field when it is append to DOM.

```
var strarray = [ "web developer", "web designer" ];
for (i = 0; i <= strarray.length-1; i++) {
    j = [{ 'emp': strarray[i] }];
    var a = j[0]['emp'];
    console.log(a);
    $("<input type='text' value=" + a + "/>")
        .attr("id", "myfieldid"+i)
        .attr("name", "myfieldid[]")
        .appendTo(".mycal");
}
```

Comment: Its working.
http://jsfiddle.net/rzuc9e2d/

One thing, instead of
$("<input type='text' value=" + a + "/>")
use
$("<input type='text' value='" + a + "'/>")

That is required if string "a" contains space, which in you case is there.

Comment: @RORY Its not working please check. and i have already try with this.jsfiddle.net/rzuc9e2d

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
var input = $("<input/>", {
    "type": 'text',
    'value': a,
    'id': "myfieldid" + i,
    'name': "myfieldid[]"
});

$(".mycal").append(input);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzuc9e2d/1/)

Comment: see the fiddle provided

Answer (score 2):

You can **[create element using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements)**

```js
var strarray = ["web developer", "web designer"];
for (i = 0; i <= strarray.length - 1; i++) {
  j = [{
    'emp': strarray[i]
  }];
  var a = j[0]['emp'];
  console.log(a);
  $("<input>", {
      'type': 'text',
      'value': a,
      'id': "myfieldid" + i,
      'name': "myfieldid[]"
    }).appendTo(".mycal");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=mycal></div>
```

Comment: @sourabh : glad to help :)